# Merge [as3-api] into [actionscript-3]/[as3]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request, synonym-request

[as3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3-api) appears to be a broad, language level tag for any question using ActionScript3

[actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3) (which is already synonymous with [as3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3)) already serves this purpose, therefore I would like to suggest/request that they be made synonymous.

[as3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3-api) is not a new tag, but is not populated with active users, making it unlikely that people going there will receive any help. It also appears that there is nothing being discussed that would not be appropriate to ask in [actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3).

Comment: It should be also noted that 88/108 of the questions in [as3-api] have the [actionscript-3] tag as well.

Comment: Suprisingly, 4 years later, there still are just 20 questions in that tag that don't have  [actionscript-3] tag @Jason.

Answer (score 2):

This wasn't a simple request anymore, as users had started to use [as3-api] for *A*mazon *S3* *API*, rather than *A*ction*S*cript *3* *API*. It needed a disambiguation before we synonimized it.

I went through the 145 questions tagged with [as3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3-api) and retagged the ones which are related to Amazon S3. I tagged them with [amazon-s3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-s3). There were a total of 6 of them, mostly from the past year, except one from 2016.

Out of the 139 remaining posts, 119 were already tagged with [actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3). I went through the remaining 20 to make sure that they were also related to actionscript 3. All of them were related to actionscript3. I went ahead and added [as3-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/as3-api) as a synonym of [actionscript-3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/actionscript-3).